# CSS doesn't load when deploying Django on Railway, because MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type

Tags: python, css, django, cs50, railway

I've completed the CS50W project 1 wiki project. Though not part of the assignment, I would like to host it online so that I can show it to my friend.
The deployment to Railway is a success but when I view the page, the CSS doesn't load. You can view my website here: https://web-production-40b27.up.railway.app/

The error message I got is this:
[image]

I think it has something to do with the static files path. Can someone help me?

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
    
STATIC_ROOT =os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Here's a breakdown of my directory tree:

```
   wiki
└── wiki
    ├── db.sqlite3
    ├── encyclopedia
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   └── __pycache__
    │   │       └── __init__.cpython-312.pyc
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── static
    │   │   └── encyclopedia
    │   │       └── styles.css
    │   ├── templates
    │   │   └── encyclopedia
    │   │       ├── create.html
    │   │       ├── edit.html
    │   │       ├── entry_page.html
    │   │       ├── error.html
    │   │       ├── index.html
    │   │       ├── layout.html
    │   │       └── search.html
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   ├── util.py
    │   ├── views.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __pycache__
    │       ├── admin.cpython-312.pyc
    │       ├── apps.cpython-312.pyc
    │       ├── models.cpython-312.pyc
    │       ├── urls.cpython-312.pyc
    │       ├── util.cpython-312.pyc
    │       ├── views.cpython-312.pyc
    │       └── __init__.cpython-312.pyc
    ├── entries
    │   ├── CSS.md
    │   ├── Django.md
    │   ├── Git.md
    │   ├── HTML.md
    │   └── Python.md
    ├── manage.py
    ├── Procfile
    ├── README.md
    ├── requirements.txt
    ├── runtime.txt
    ├── staticfiles
    │   ├── admin
    │   │   ├── css
    │   │   │   ├── autocomplete.css
    │   │   │   ├── base.css
    │   │   │   ├── changelists.css
    │   │   │   ├── dark_mode.css
    │   │   │   ├── dashboard.css
    │   │   │   ├── forms.css
    │   │   │   ├── login.css
    │   │   │   ├── nav_sidebar.css
    │   │   │   ├── responsive.css
    │   │   │   ├── responsive_rtl.css
    │   │   │   ├── rtl.css
    │   │   │   ├── vendor
    │   │   │   │   └── select2
    │   │   │   │       ├── LICENSE-SELECT2.md
    │   │   │   │       ├── select2.css
    │   │   │   │       └── select2.min.css
    │   │   │   └── widgets.css
    │   │   ├── img
    │   │   │   ├── calendar-icons.svg
    │   │   │   ├── gis
    │   │   │   │   ├── move_vertex_off.svg
    │   │   │   │   └── move_vertex_on.svg
    │   │   │   ├── icon-addlink.svg
    │   │   │   ├── icon-alert.svg
    │   │   │   ├── icon-calendar.svg
    │   │   │   ├── icon-changelink.svg
    │   │   │   ├── icon-clock.svg
    │   │   │   ├── icon-deletelink.svg
    │   │   │   ├── icon-hidelink.svg
    │   │   │   ├── icon-no.svg
    │   │   │   ├── icon-unknown-alt.svg
    │   │   │   ├── icon-unknown.svg
    │   │   │   ├── icon-viewlink.svg
    │   │   │   ├── icon-yes.svg
    │   │   │   ├── inline-delete.svg
    │   │   │   ├── LICENSE
    │   │   │   ├── README.txt
    │   │   │   ├── search.svg
    │   │   │   ├── selector-icons.svg
    │   │   │   ├── sorting-icons.svg
    │   │   │   ├── tooltag-add.svg
    │   │   │   └── tooltag-arrowright.svg
    │   │   └── js
    │   │       ├── actions.js
    │   │       ├── admin
    │   │       │   ├── DateTimeShortcuts.js
    │   │       │   └── RelatedObjectLookups.js
    │   │       ├── autocomplete.js
    │   │       ├── calendar.js
    │   │       ├── cancel.js
    │   │       ├── change_form.js
    │   │       ├── collapse.js
    │   │       ├── core.js
    │   │       ├── filters.js
    │   │       ├── inlines.js
    │   │       ├── jquery.init.js
    │   │       ├── nav_sidebar.js
    │   │       ├── popup_response.js
    │   │       ├── prepopulate.js
    │   │       ├── prepopulate_init.js
    │   │       ├── SelectBox.js
    │   │       ├── SelectFilter2.js
    │   │       ├── theme.js
    │   │       ├── urlify.js
    │   │       └── vendor
    │   │           ├── jquery
    │   │           │   ├── jquery.js
    │   │           │   ├── jquery.min.js
    │   │           │   └── LICENSE.txt
    │   │           ├── select2
    │   │           │   ├── i18n
    │   │           │   │   ├── af.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── ar.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── az.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── bg.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── bn.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── bs.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── ca.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── cs.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── da.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── de.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── dsb.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── el.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── en.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── es.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── et.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── eu.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── fa.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── fi.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── fr.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── gl.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── he.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── hi.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── hr.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── hsb.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── hu.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── hy.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── id.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── is.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── it.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── ja.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── ka.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── km.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── ko.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── lt.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── lv.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── mk.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── ms.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── nb.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── ne.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── nl.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── pl.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── ps.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── pt-BR.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── pt.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── ro.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── ru.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── sk.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── sl.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── sq.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── sr-Cyrl.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── sr.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── sv.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── th.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── tk.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── tr.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── uk.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── vi.js
    │   │           │   │   ├── zh-CN.js
    │   │           │   │   └── zh-TW.js
    │   │           │   ├── LICENSE.md
    │   │           │   ├── select2.full.js
    │   │           │   └── select2.full.min.js
    │   │           └── xregexp
    │   │               ├── LICENSE.txt
    │   │               ├── xregexp.js
    │   │               └── xregexp.min.js
    │   └── encyclopedia
    │       └── styles.css
    └── wiki
        ├── asgi.py
        ├── settings.py
        ├── urls.py
        ├── wsgi.py
        ├── __init__.py
        └── __pycache__
            ├── settings.cpython-312.pyc
            ├── urls.cpython-312.pyc
            ├── wsgi.cpython-312.pyc
            └── __init__.cpython-312.pyc
```

Comment: Hint: Have you tried opening the CSS file in your browser? https://web-production-40b27.up.railway.app/static/encyclopedia/styles.css You will need extra steps to serve static assets when `DEBUG = False`. See similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your network tab in your web inspector:

[image: Network tab]

Fetching the stylesheet results in status code 404. This means that the resource is not present in the path.

Fixing this issue is not as simple as fixing the path to the resource. This is because in production (i.e. `DEBUG = False`), Django does not serve static files by itself. Django does list out methods of deploying static files in production [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/deployment/), however, I find these methods rather difficult to understand. You may want to install **whitenoise** found [here](https://whitenoise.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django.html), which has elaborate instructions on how to set up.

Comment: What I did was I followed the steps in link you provided:https://whitenoise.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django.html#check-its-working

i found out that I need to add `{% load static %}` just above my `<link href="{% static 'encyclopedia/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Comment: Then I added whitenoise to the middleware. Then i encountered (staticfiles.W004) The directory in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist error in django error, so I have to create a static file in the wiki folder to jump over this error.